# modal box has overlays opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have and overlay and another div tha must appears over the overlay but it takes overlays opacity.

My code:

Styles:

```
    #mymodal{
    width:400px; 
    padding-bottom:1px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    box-shadow:0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 620000;
    opacity:1;
    visibility:visible;
    }

   #blackoverlaynd{
   position: fixed; 
   left: 0px; 
   top: 0px; 
   width:100%; 
   height:100%; 
   z-index: 300000; 
   background-color: #000; 
   opacity:0.90; 
   cursor: pointer;
   }


    <div id="mymodal"></div>    
    <div id="blackoverlaynd"></div>
```

any ideas why it's happening?

Comment: @VotetoClose It's not a child inheritance problem. Look at the html markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is how opacity behaves.

You can consider the following markup:

```
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-background">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-content">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.modal-background {
    opacity: 0.9
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not taking `blackoverlaynd`'s Opacity,

Your problem is that `z-index` only works on `relative`, `absolute`, and `fixed` positioned elements. Set `mymodal` to `position:relative` and you'll be all set.